# How to pass array from kendo preflight to MVC list parameter?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, kendo-ui

I have a web endpoint

```cs
public JsonResult GetCompanyPersonnelMany(string text, IEnumerable<int> includeIds)
{
```

I want to pass some data from a kendo multiselect. The multi select uses server side filtering; it uses a remote datasource; and it needs to process the data pre-flight.

My problem is that the `text` parameter will be set, but `includeIds` is always empty.

The pre-flight method looks like

```js
var employeeComboDataPreFlight_loading = true;
function employeeComboDataPreFlight() {
    var data = multiSelectPreFlightCommon(getMultiSelectByName('personnel'));
    if (employeeComboDataPreFlight_loading) { data.includeIds = [568,572,585] || []; }
    return data;
}
```

The multiselect is defined in the view as

```cs
@(Html.Kendo().MultiSelect()
    .Name("personnel")
    .Filter(FilterType.Contains)
    .Placeholder("Select an option...")
    .DataTextField(nameof(PersonnelEmployerViewModel.DisplayName))
    .DataValueField(nameof(PersonnelEmployerViewModel.PersonnelId))
    .MinLength(2)
    .Value(Model.Select(x => x.PersonnelId))
    .DataSource(source =>
    {
      source.Read(read =>
      {
          read.Action(nameof(PersonnelController.GetCompanyPersonnelMany),
              ControllerName.Personnel
              )
          .Data("employeeComboDataPreFlight")
          ;
      })
      .ServerFiltering(true);
    })
    )
```

Evaluating the pre-flight method (in chrome console) shows the following:

```
> employeeComboDataPreFlight()
<- {text: "", includeIds: Array(3)}
    includeIds: Array(3)
      0: 568
      1: 572
      2: 585
> JSON.stringify(employeeComboDataPreFlight())
<- "{"text":"","includeIds":[568,572,585]}"
```

Opening the chrome network tab, it shows Query String Parameters:

```
text:
includeIds[]: 568
includeIds[]: 572
includeIds[]: 585
```

And my request URL:

```
Request URL: https://localhost:44363/Personnel/GetCompanyPersonnelMany?text=&includeIds%5B%5D=568&includeIds%5B%5D=572&includeIds%5B%5D=585
```

So it looks like there is an array of data for a variable named `includeIds` being sent to the server.

My problem is that the controller isn't getting the the `includeIds` parameter (the `text` parameter works correctly), the List is always empty (non-null, length: 0). How do I get the kendo multiselect to pass my javascript array into a format the controller will accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the problem is the same as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28855763/how-to-pass-a-list-of-ids-in-a-ajax-request-to-the-server-in-mvc/28856506) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56382671/how-to-pass-array-object-as-a-parameter-in-kendo-datasource-read-methods).

As pointed out in [the documentation](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/configuration/transport.read) the read transport is a wrapper to jquery ajax method, so (some of) the same configuration parameters can be passed through. The fix is to pass `traditional: true` to the read transport configuration. This is not possible using the MVC wrappers, so you have to define the kendo widget in javascript.

I tried setting the option after the widget was initialized like in [this post](https://www.telerik.com/forums/changing-the-contenttype-in-the-http-request#db5uWGfZIUmIOkEz91V8ig) but couldn't get this to work:

```js
multiselect.dataSource.transport.options.read.traditional = true; // doesn't do anything
```

I also tried to use `JSON.stringify` instead of `traditional` but couldn't ever get a working request. In the end, I had to (1) change from MVC to javascript definition of the widget and (2) add `traditional: true` to transport options. The view now looks like

```html
<div id="personnelWrapper" name="personnel"></div>
<script>
    $("#personnelWrapper").kendoMultiSelect({
        "filter": "contains",
        "placeholder": "Select an option...",
        "dataTextField": "@nameof(PersonnelEmployerViewModel.DisplayName)",
        "dataValueField": "@nameof(PersonnelEmployerViewModel.PersonnelId)",
        "minLength": 2,
        "value": [@(string.Join(",", Model.Select(x => x.PersonnelId)))],
        "dataSource": {
            "transport": {
                "read": {
                    "url": "@(Url.Action(nameof(PersonnelController.GetCompanyPersonnelMany),
                          ControllerName.Personnel) )",
                    "dataType": "json",
                    "data":employeeComboDataPreFlight,
                    "traditional": true, // <- this is the solution
                },
                "prefix":""
            },
            "serverFiltering":true,
            "filter":[],
            "schema":{
                "errors":"Errors"
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```